# Google Sheets SUMIFS where multiple criteria is returning 0

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am struggling to workout the correct `Google Sheets` formula to achieve the following.

In the sheet `Profile` below, column `Purchased_Classes`, I want to `SUMIF` the `Qty` in sheet `Purchased_Completed`, Where the `Email` matches and `Item` contains the text "`Class`"

I have tried this but the results is returning `0`

Here is a [link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1q9VRLwcP5q7YV8tFOAVW5SdOvo63XGtT0qu5jJYNSfw) to a sample google sheet.

```
={"Purchased_Classes";ARRAYFORMULA(IF(ISBLANK(A2:A),"",SUMIFS(Purchases_Completed!H2:H,Purchases_Completed!B2:B,A2:A,ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Class",Purchases_Completed!C2:C)), TRUE)))}
```

.

```
Profile
```

[image]

```
Purchases_Completed
```

[image]

Comment: Please share a copy of your spreadsheet (excluding private or confidential information) and include an example of a successful outcome.

Comment: If this is google sheets, then don’t tag excel...

Comment: @Tedinoz I have edited my question to include a link to a sample google sheet.

Comment: Thanks. But it requires permission; can you share without needing permission?

Comment: @Tedinoz sorry - try again :)

Comment: Great, would you add an extra column showing what values you expect in a successful outcome.

Comment: I've added a column wit the expected values for each row and an explanation

Comment: User 3 had sales of 10 units

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try and create an empty sheet with the following formula:

```
=QUERY(Purchases_Completed!A2:H, "SELECT B, SUM(H) WHERE C LIKE '%Class%' GROUP BY B LABEL B 'Email', SUM(H) 'Purchased_Classes'")
```

This formula uses [`QUERY`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343?hl=en) and it calculates the sum of your items which contain the 'Class' keyword for each user.

Here is the result using the query:

[image: Example result]

You can learn more about the Google Query Language [here](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/querylanguage).

Comment: Thanks - But I'm struggling to make it work in my original sheet. The `Email` Col in the `Profile` sheet is copied from another sheet (called `App:Logins`) and so there already exists a formula in that cell which can't be replaced with your suggested one. How can I apply your suggested `QUERY` formula so that it can be used in the current `Purchases_Complete` Col B of the sheet?

Comment: Or I could still use your suggested solution in another Col of the same sheet, but I need to order results by the original Col A `Email` - How can I do that? I have tried adding the `ORDER BY B` after the GROUP BY syntax but I'm getting a parse error :/

Comment: nevermind, I've used your solution in a separate sheet and I'm referencing the values to copy them across to another sheet.